# Greater than Index in Django

Tags: python, django, indexing, django-3.2

In Django-3.2 class Index get a positional argument *expressions* which allows to create functional indexes on expressions

Is it possible to create index on Integer field with expression greater? For example

My model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

Usually I have a filter (quantity>0). How to create expression index on that?

Comment: Isn't a simple index on quantity sufficient? This is a B-tree, and thus already will work quite fast to determine the objects, and the advantage is that this can be used for any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ExpressionWrapper` to create a functional index:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Index, Q

class Product(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            Index(
                ExpressionWrapper(
                    Q(quantity__gt=0),
                    output_field=BooleanField()
                ),
            name='some_name_for_the_constraint'
          )
        ]
```

Which will be translated in SQL to:

```
CREATE INDEX `some_name_for_the_constraint`
          ON `app_name_product` ((`quantity` > 0));
```

Typically however a [**`db_index=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index), will suffice to speed up filter since these are typically implemented by some tree-like structure, and thus will determine the objects to retrieve in *O(log n)*.

We thus can set this to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        db_index=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
```

This will work reasonable fast.